# Access class properties from CreateJS event listener function?

Tags: easeljs, createjs, event-listener

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and CreateJS.
Here is my code:

```
var ClassName = function(){
this.mc = new createjs.MovieClip();
//...Add graphic to this.mc code
createjs.Tween.get(this.mc).to({scaleY:0, y:50},300).call(onTweenCompleted);
}
ClassName.prototype.onTweenCompleted = function(){
console.log(this.mc.y);
}
```

My problem is that when TweenComplete call onTweenCompleted properties **this.mc.y** is not accessible. Here an error I got:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'y' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a scope in the function call e.g. like this:

```
createjs.Tween.get(this.mc).to({scaleY:0, y:50},300).call(onTweenCompleted, [], this);
```

Comment: Hey Thank man! I just check the TweenJS doc this is also work. Thank